# Search for same values into multiple csv files

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder with 100+ csv files with several columns and hundreds of rows.Im trying to find a way to export into a new csv all the values (from a specific column) that exists into more than 1 file.

ex.

**1.csv**

```
ID,LOC,DATA
01,DUBAI,**AA**
02,LONDON,AB
03,ROME,AW
```

**2.csv**

```
ID,LOC,DATA
04,NEW YORK,AC
05,CHICAGO,**AA**
06,LOS ANGELES,AR
```

**3.csv**

```
ID,LOC,DATA
07,BERLIN,**AA**
08,TOKYO,**AA**
09,MOSCOW,AL
```

In the example above the desired export is the AA value.
edit.It would be handy if at the end the exported value would come with whole row

Comment: You can iterate through the 100+ csv files and append each duplicate values in a list. After iterating, you can use the list of duplicate values to create a new csv file.

Comment: This looks like a job for `grep` or `awk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pythons built-in [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the occurrences of each value:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    column_name = "DATA"
    counter = Counter()
    headers = None
    rows = []

    directory = os.path.join("/path/to/csv/files/")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        files = [file for file in files if file.endswith(".csv")]
        for file in files:
            with open(file, "r") as f:
                data = list(csv.reader(f))
                if data:
                    headers = data.pop(0)

                    for i in range(len(headers)):
                        if headers[i] == column_name:
                            column_data = list(zip(*data))[i]
                            counter.update(column_data)

        for file in files:
            with open(file, "r") as f:
                data = list(csv.DictReader(f))
                for row in data:
                    if counter[row[column_name]] > 1:
                        rows.append(row.values())

    with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: thanks for your try but by this code you are just printing into console the values that are same into specific file and not between all files.

Comment: @yoloko that's true, I've updated my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: It works like a charm with the given .csv files.The last step is to not define the csv but get all files containg into the folder.Something like glob should do the job you think?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, do you want to copy all csv files which contain duplicate data to a certain folder?

Comment: No, i just want to get the values that exist in multiple .csv files more than 1time.your code its exactly what i want but you set a list of defined files " files = ["1.csv", "2.csv", "3.csv"]"  I want to get all files from folder

Comment: I see, I've made a last update, now you can specify a directory where it will read all csv files :)

Comment: Its EXACTLY what i wanted.Thank you very much!!